# Conditional join in ef core

Tags: entity-framework

I have a query where I want to make conditional left or right join on table. For example in below query if PriorNavPositions has more record than SourceInvestorAllocations then left join to fecth all records from PriorNavPositions else if SourceInvestorAllocations have more records than PriorNavPositions then right join to fetch all records from SourceInvestorAllocations. I am ok with conditional multiple queries as well. Any help appreciated

```
        var query = (from pn in PriorNavPositions
                 join sa in SourceDataset.SourceInvestorAllocations on
                    new { SourceDatasetId = pn.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = pn.SubscriberFiid, ShareIndex = pn.ShareIndex } equals
                    new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } into groupJoinResult
                 from sa in groupJoinResult.DefaultIfEmpty(new SourceInvestorAllocation() { 
                     Strategy = pn.ShareClass, EFrontInteger = pn.ShareIndex, SourceDataset = new SourceDataset() { Id=pn.SourceDatasetId } 
                 })
                 join ea in EfrontNavDataset.EfrontNavInvestorAllocations on
                    new { SourceDatasetId = sa.SourceDataset.Id, Iqid = sa.IqId, ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger } equals
                    new { SourceDatasetId = ea.EfrontNavDataset.SourceDatasetId, Iqid = ea.IqId, ShareIndex = ea.ShareIndex } into pnj
                 from ea in pnj.DefaultIfEmpty(new EfrontNavInvestorAllocation(){ ShareIndex = sa.EFrontInteger })
                 select new { sa, ea, pn });
```

Comment: Do both right and left join and put you condition as part of the join statement.